# How can I get which shortcuts and files are highlighted in a folder path like the desktop

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I looked around on msdn and this was the only thing close to what I need 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

but it doesn't seem to have any function that returns a boolean that has weather or not a object is highlighted. There must be a function like this somewhere that windows uses otherwise how would you be able to drag icons? And highlighting a bunch of them and then opening them all wouldn't be possible either.

Comment: This combined with the special desktop folder can help if you read into it and look at other functions that are available: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx

Comment: Looking around, there's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775610(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you chris I could not find these with the multiple things I put into google

Comment: I know that feeling well. These would have helped me a ton in high school and then I just stumbled upon the first one (randomly, soon after giving up searching) when I needed it for something different.

Comment: haha all the best to you. I just finished highschool myself I guess I am the same year as you according to your profile, that is if I was going to school

Answer (score 1):

The above comments appear to only be a solution to getting the count of selected items(?) - If you're still looking for a solution I found an implementation here (I'm not sure if it's a good way of doing it however):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/20/188696.aspx